# Word count with common words - haskell

Tags: haskell

I am working on a little project using Haskell. I want to count the number of words in a paragraph or a few sentences, along with any common words according
to the Oxford English Corpus (OEC) rank.

I have some code to work from however I am new to Haskell and would require some help.

```
 <your code here>

 text = "the best book in the world is harry potter. my favourite author is 
 JK Rowling."

  main = do
   let wordCount = toWordCount text
   putStrLn "Report:"
   putStrLn ("\t" ++ (show $ length wordlist) ++ " words")
   putStrLn ("\t" ++ (show $ countCommonWords wordlist) ++ " common words")
```

expected outcome should be something like this

```
 Report:
  15 words
   5 common words
```

help would be appreciated to get me started on this new language.

thanks

so far the only attempt i have been able to make is,

```
 import Data.List (nub) 
 import Data.Char (toLower)

 toWordCount ns xs = map (\x -> length (filter (==x) xs)) ns
 nubl = nub . map (map toLower) -- to lowercase

 wordCount ws =  zip ns (countCommonWords ns ws)
 where ns = nubl ws
```

that's the best attempt i have made, any solutions would be helpful

Comment: Do you have any ideas of your own?

Comment: Try yourself first. Show us where you get stuck, and tell us why you think it's impossible to make progress there. We will help you over that hump, and then you can iterate.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are new to haskell and StackOverflow, let me give you some hints. The full solution is up to you.

- First you need to remove punctuation marks in order to avoid `is!` to be different from `is`. Check `filter` function
- Once you have your phrase "mark-less" you can count how many words there are. check function `words`
- if you have a list of common words you can intersect it with your list of words and count how many are in both lists. check `Data.List` library, you'll find useful functions for doing so.

If you get stacked, update the question and **post your attempt**